# Как получать данные из хранилища до создания активности?

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, android-shared-preferences

Для смены темы приложения я использую пользовательское значение
Чтобы корректно произвести смену темы, необходимо получать данные о настройке до создания активности
У меня было 3 варианта сохранения и чтения данных:

1. SharedPreference
2. ORM
3. Свой SQLiteOpenHelper

Для получения доступа к преференсу требуется контекст, который не получается получить до создания активности, ORM требует прописать имя приложения в манифесте, которое уже занято моим файлом (в данной ситуации можно попробовать форкнуть код ORM, внести в него мой код и спокойно дать имя приложению в манифесте), SQLiteOpenHelper также требует контекст, который не получается получить до создания активности

**Хотелось бы услышать возможные варианты получения данных, записанных ранее, до создания активности, в которой эти данные будут использоваться**

Comment: Что такое `до создания активности?` Вообще, до (и даже вместо) активити могут быть сначала созданы Application и/или ContentProvider. В них есть доступ к контексту. Скорее всего вы его (контекст) неправильно (не там/не так) пытаетесь получить. Что за проблема с ORM и манифестом - совершенно непонятно. ORM очень много разных, возможно вам стоит уточнить про какую вы. Де-факто стандартом является Room. SQLiteOpenHelper, как писалось выше, не имеет проблем с контекстом, однако его использовать - лютое извращение, если есть Room и если вам могут и префы подойти.

Comment: из того, что понял я: можно воспользоваться вьюмоделью, она переживает пересоздание  активити - гадание на гуще

Comment: а почему бы не делать это в Активити, но ДО методов super.onCreate
        setContentView. я так с языками делаю, не думаю, что "тема" будет отличаться.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб до создания активности - до метода onCreate
Использую Sugar ORM

Comment: @Wlad я так и пытался делать, но не смог получить контекст до onCreate()

Comment: https://sun9-27.userapi.com/impg/NYF4A3XwW15gZckQ2XulIpS7eyd_wl9EBfhc5w/hNwxKi7H26o.jpg?size=878x380&quality=96&sign=102cc4c4adacce55e987cf33718d8dab&type=album  вот скрин моего рабочего кода. внутри метода onCreate до вызова super контекст спокойно получается. (строчки 28-29)

Comment: @Wlad большое спасибо за помощь)) Сделал как показано у Вас (по этому принципу) и всё работает)) Откуда-то запомнил, что ничего до супер-метода нельзя писать

Comment: @НикитаПопов ну вообще "да". лучше ничего туда не писать. но в случаях, когда надо сменить язык или тему, от которых зависит логика метода setContentView - можно и нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Активити - не первый компонент, создающийся при запуске приложения. У истока стоит объект Application, который имеет свой жизненный цикл.  В частности - метод onCreate, вызывающийся до onCreate() главной активности, или любого другого компонента, который послужил точкой входа. В нем можно проинициализировать все, что надо. (Напомню, что у Application есть контекст). А вообще для этих целей есть Dagger/Hilt.